# How to iterate over one or more arguments in bison?

Tags: compiler-construction, bison, context-free-grammar

I have the following grammar:

```
structdef  : 'struct' TOK_IDENT '{'[fielddecl]+;'}'  {$$ = $2->adopt(all fielddecl)}
```

$2 is a node created for an abstract sintax tree which adopts one or more nodes returned by 'fielddecls'. The problem is that I don't know how to do this type of iteration in Bison.

Bad approach:

```
structdef  : 'struct' TOK_IDENT '{'fielddecls;'}'  {$$ = $2->adopt($4);}
           ;
fielddecls : fielddecl {$$ = $1}
           | fielddecs fielddec {$$ = $2->adopt($1);}
           |
           ;
fielddec   : terminal_symbol
```

As you can see, this is a bad approach because the depth of the tree becomes very high.

How would you approach this?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, but it looks similar to what would be the standard approach. What problems is the depth of the parse tree causing for you?

Comment: It becomes very high. I was hoping the node can adopt its children normally without creating an embedded linked-list in the tree.

Comment: Yes, it'll become deep if there are many items in the sequence. Again, how is that a problem?

Comment: I think you might be confused by the difference between a parse tree and an AST. In the former, the number of children a node has is constant and determined by the rule it matched; in the latter, a node can have a varying number of children.